# Algorithm to find the vertices of the equidistant lines between N closed polygonal lines

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, linear-programming

I have a set $\{C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_N\}$ of $N$ nonintersecting closed piecewise linear curves on the Euclidean plane. For every point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we say it belongs to a territory serviced by $C_i$ if $C_i$ is closest curve to $x$.

The boundaries of territories serviced by the $C_i$'s are clearly polygonal lines themselves (???). I am looking for the algorithm to find the vertices of each boundary.

Thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a "closed polygonal line" is a line segment.
If so, the boundaries of the "territories serviced" are not polygonal,
but rather contain parabolic arcs as well:

---

[image: VoronoiSegments]

---

Search for the *Voronoi diagram of line segments*,
and you will find,
e.g., Meera Sitharam's lecture notes, 
([PDF download](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sitharam/COURSES/CG/kreveldmorevoronoi.pdf)),
which include the above image.

---

After the OP clarified that "closed piecewise linear curve"
means "polygon," the situation is still pretty much the same:

---

[image: VoronoiPolygons]

        

<sup>(Image from [Boost Voronoi Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_main.htm).)</sup>

---

Comment: I mean nonintersecting piecewise linear curves. But I guess the equidistant line is still not polygonal

Comment: I added an image of the Voronoi diagram of polygons.